# Saving a nested for loop output to matrix array

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have two dataframes that look this (in reality they are different dimensions).

```
sample_df <- as.data.frame(NA)
sample_df[1:4, 1:5] <- NA
sample_df[1, 1:5] <- rnorm(5)
sample_df[2, 1:5] <- rnorm(5)
sample_df[3, 1:5] <- rnorm(5)
sample_df[4, 1:5] <- rnorm(5)
```

```
conversion <- as.data.frame(NA)
conversion[1:5, 1:3] <- NA
conversion[1, 1:3] <- rnorm(3)
conversion[2, 1:3] <- rnorm(3)
conversion[3, 1:3] <- rnorm(3)
conversion[4, 1:3] <- rnorm(3)
conversion[5, 1:3] <- rnorm(3)
```

I am trying to do the following caclulation through a loop, savin to a list of dataframes. In this case, the output be a list of 4 data frames, each with 5 rows and 3 columns This code is not working because it won't save the output. Any suggestions?

```
output <- list()
for (j in 1:nrow(sample_df)){   
  for (i in 1:nrow(conversion))    { 
    output[[j]][i,] <- sample_df[j,i]*conversion[i,]
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I fixed it in the question

Comment: Please provide your data with dput(). You can use `dput(sample_df)`

Comment: As is, you have still not provided a minimal reproducible example

Comment: it is now reproducible

Comment: ``output[i,,j]`` should be ``output[i,j]``

Comment: that does not work.... see my updated question